# Measurability of Banach space valued function

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, measurable-functions, bochner-spaces

If $u \in L^2(0,T; L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$, then can we say $u$ is measurable on $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^d$?

I tried to use the simple functions, which converge to $u(t)$ with respect to $\Vert \cdot\Vert_2$ a.e. $t\in (0,T)$, to approximate $u(t,x)$ a.e. $(t,x) \in (0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^d$, but it doesn't seem to work well since $(0,T)$ is a uncountable set.

Could you help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: $u(t)$ is a square integrable function for all $t$??? That is a strange beast.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean? $u$ is a sqaured Bochner intergrable function, i.e., $u(t) \mapsto \Vert u\Vert_2$ is a strongly measurable function and $\int_0^T \Vert u\Vert_2^2 \,dt < \infty$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $L^2(0,T; \mathbb{R}^d)$? If not you might want to emphasise that you are dealing with $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ valued functions.

Comment: @copper.hat Definitely not. $u$ is a Banach space valued function. Here, the Banach space in question is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Please look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for the null function $u=0$, a "badly" chosen selection $u(t)$ need not be measurable if you assume the continuum hypothesis. Indeed, asssuming the continuum hypothesis, there is a set $M\subseteq[0,1]^2$ such that $u(t,s)=\chi_M(t,s)$ has the property that for every $t$ there holds $u(t,s)=0$ for all but countably many $s$, and for every $s$ there holds $u(t,s)=1$ for all but countably many $t$. (This is a famour example of Sierpinski and can be found e.g. in Rudin's "Real and complex analysis").

On the other hand, there is a result that there does exist a "good" selection. More precisely, there exists a product-measurable function $u$ such that for every $t$ there holds $u(t)(s)=u(t,s)$ for almost all $s$. A proof of the latter is IIRC in Hille-Philips monograph about semigroups. A more general result, also for the converse assertion, is contained in my monograph [M. Väth, Ideal Spaces (Springer, Berlin 1997)](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540631606).

Comment: Thank you very much! So, to put it simply, we cannot generally say $u(t,x)$ is measurable on $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^d$, right?

Comment: Yes, in general this cannot be said.

Comment: Hi, I think your answer is correct, but I found that in some books, they say $L^p(0,T; L^p(\Omega))$ is naturally identified (isomorphic to) $L^p((0,T)\times \Omega)$. For example, in the book titled "THE THREE-DIMENSIONAL
NAVIER–STOKES EQUATIONS" by Robinson, Rodrigo and  Sadowski.(p.39). Of course, they don't have proof of it. I will post the screenshots in the next post. Would you help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the book titled "THE THREE-DIMENSIONAL NAVIER–STOKES EQUATIONS" by Robinson, Rodrigo and Sadowski

[image]

2. In the book titled "Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications" by Tomásˇ Roubícˇ ek

[image]

Comment: Yes, in PDE books there are often such handwavy arguments used, but rarely proved or correctly cited, and sometimes with inaccuracies (the classical book of Hille-Philipps I mentioned is an exception). An example is your second citation which omits the ugly details about the "natural isomorphism" (and actually in case $q=\infty$ this "natural isomorphism" is not onto if one would formulate (1.61) in the obvious way for that case).

Comment: @MartinVäth Thank you very much for getting back to me! Can I ask you something? Actually, as a student who studies PDE, it is really torturous to see those kinds of things. More specifically, I think one of the pillars of mathematics is its rigorousness, even though intuition (is thought to) drives mathematics. What if somebody takes a wrong result to develop his argument and says he proved a theorem. Take the question I asked above. Almost nobody wouldn't check the measurability of (the strong measurable) $u$ on $(0, T)\times \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @MartinVäth However, for me, I almost always want to check those types of trivial things, because if there are any holes or gaps between mathematical arguments, the theorem or the conclusions based on them don't hold. I suppose if we are determined to be super picky about every technicality and try to check it in every book and paper, we could find lots of holes and gaps in their arguments, even though no one would dare to do it. The point is I don't know what to do whenever I encounter those types of things. Is this only PDE? Could you say something to me regarding this? I am really serious.

Comment: In my experience, the more applied a community is, the less care they take about the "foundational" details. Also there are many "folklore" results which everybody in a community takes as granted and nobody ever re-checks (you cannot publish a paper on it and you are considered strange if you write a long passage in a paper about it), although in the course of time sometimes some details got lost. I agree that this is a problem in the way research is organized nowadays. BTW, there is an estimate that about 1/10 of research papers contain non-trivial bugs.

Comment: To stick with Mathematics: The claim about the "isomorphism" is correct in one direction even if $q=\infty$: If $T,S$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, $Y=L_q(S)$ and $u\colon T\to Y$ is (strongly Bochner) measurable then there is a product measurable $\widetilde u$ such that $[u(t)](s)=\widetilde u(t,s)$ for almost all $(t,s)\in T\times S$ (the point is: in general not for *all* $t,s$). The problem in case $q=\infty$ is the converse even if $T=S=[0,1]$: If $\widetilde u$ is measurable then $u$ is in general not strongly measurable in case $q=\infty$.

Comment: This is not the place for such discussions. Yes, I was sort of professor and supervising Ph.D students.

Comment: @MartinVäth Thank you for your answer. By the way, with your remark on the isomorphism between two spaces, you said there is isomorphism "in one direction". Even for $1 \le p < \infty$, isomorphism doesn't hold? (I mean, both directions). Also, if $u = \chi_M$, which you gave in your answer post, then we cannot say that $[u(t)](s) = u(t,s)$ since $u(t,s)$ is not a product measurable function. Then, how can we find a product measurable $\tilde{u}(t,s)$ such that $[u(t)](s) = \tilde{u}(t,s)$. Is it contained in your book?

Comment: $p$ does not matter; the problem is only $q=\infty$. If $\Delta=\{(t,s):0\le s\le t\}$ then $u(t)(s)=\chi_\Delta(t,s)$ is not strongly measurabe as a function $u\colon[0,1]\to L_\infty([0,1])$ (because $u([0,1]\setminus N)$ is non-separable for every null-set $N$), but $u\colon[0,1]\to L_q([0,1])$ is measurable if $q<\infty$.

In my book is shown: If $u\colon T\to X$ is strongly measurable ($X$ an ideal space) then there is a measurable $\widetilde u$ with $u(t)(s)=\widetilde u(t,s)$ a.e. (idea of proof: approximation by simple functions); the converse is shown also if $X$ is regular.

Comment: @MartinVäth Thank you very much for your answer! I will look it up in your book!

Comment: @MartinVäth Hi, I tried to find the result in your book that there is a measurable $\tilde{u}$ with $u(t)(s) = \tilde{u}(t,s)$ a.e for $1 \le p < \infty$, but I couldn't find it because it might be described in a more abstract form. Could you tell me where in the book it is shown?

Comment: Theorem 4.4.1: it is even shown that it is possible to choose $\widetilde u$ such that the equality holds for every $t$ for almost every $s$ (the null set can depend on $t$). The converse implication for regular spaces is contained in Theorem 4.4.2.

Comment: @MartinVäth Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Hi, can I ask you a question about your remark: "If $u: T \to X$ is strongly measurable ($X$ an ideal space), then there is a measurable $\tilde{u}$ with $u(t)(s) = \tilde{u}$ a.e." I am wondering whether this a.e. means for almost every $t$ in $L^p(L^p)$, or for almost every $(t,x)$. Since if it's the latter, then for the $\chi_M$, which is not measurable on $(t,x)$ assuming the continuum hypothesis, there is a measurable function $\tilde{u}(t,x)$ such that $\chi_M = \tilde{u}$ for a.e. $(t,x)$ and it means $\chi_M$ is also Lebesgue measurable on $(t,x)$. So, I think it needs clarification.

Comment: (Removed my last comment, since it was wrong and I could no longer edit it.)

You are right: The exact assertion is that for (almost) all $t$ the equality holds for almost all $x$ (the exceptional set can depend on $t$). It follows that the equality holds for a.a. $(t,x)$ if and only if you choose a representation for almost every $t$ such that $(t,x)\mapsto u(t)(x)$ is product measurable (the first part implies that such a representation exists).